# Calculation of total resistance and total power of a circuit with different power values?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, resistance

Two resistors of 10 ohms and 5 ohms are connected in series with *different powers, 1W and 2W* respectively. What is the total resistance and total power?

Comment: Have you done the math yet?

Comment: total resistance will b 15oham, but what about watts..

Comment: sir give me answer, im student

Comment: *"sir give me answer, im student"* You're not any kind of student I would recognise. VTC for dumping a homework question with zero effort and zero respect.

Comment: this is inform you that if you dont want to answer then dont post comment like that, i am not suppose to come to you and begged for answer. question is question... why do you think its dump or homework.... every one has question... you cant assume what kind of question should be my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The resistances add when in series, as you already found out. The power dissipated at a resistance is \$P = R*I^2\$. We know that

$$ P_1 = 10\Omega * I_1^2 = 1W \rightarrow I_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1W}{10\Omega}} = 316mA $$
$$ P_2 = 5\Omega * I_2^2 = 2W \rightarrow I_2 = \sqrt{\frac{2W}{5\Omega}} = 632.5mA $$

When both are in series, we shouldn't be surpassing the smaller maximum current as to not go over a single power rating. The combined maximum dissipated power is then:

$$ P_{max} = (10\Omega + 5\Omega) * (316mA)^2 = 1.5W $$